# Boton bloqueado

Tags: android, android-studio, diseño

quisiera saber como le puedo hacer en android un boton que diga aceptar y otro comprar y que su funcion sea que por ejemplo yo ingreso ciertas cantidades en un formulario y primero debo dar en clic aceptar, si yo doy en el boton de comprar solo me debe arrojar un toast que diga "primero acepta tu compra" y cuando yo le de aceptar cuando los campos esten llenos el boton de comprar debera de funcionar, como le puedo hacer??

```
package com.example.danhermes.despensa;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class despensa extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etinicio, etarticulo, etcantidad ;
Button btnaceptar, btncomprar, btnceditar;
TextView tvporcentaje, tvdisponible, tvcompra;
ProgressBar pbarra;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.despensa);
    etinicio = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etinicio));
    etarticulo = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etarticulo));
    etcantidad = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etcantidad));
    tvcompra = (TextView) (super.findViewById(R.id.tvcompra));
    tvdisponible = (TextView) (super.findViewById(R.id.tvdisponible));

    btncomprar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btncomprar));
    btnaceptar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btnaceptar));
    btnceditar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btnceditar));

    tvporcentaje = (TextView) (super.findViewById(R.id.tvporcentaje));

    btnaceptar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btncomprar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnceditar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnaceptar) {
        if (etinicio.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etarticulo.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etcantidad.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ingresa una cantidad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }else{
            etinicio.setEnabled(false);
            etarticulo.setEnabled(false);
            etcantidad.setEnabled(false);
            btncomprar.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btncomprar && etinicio.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etarticulo.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etcantidad.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Accion No permitida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }else{
        try{
            double inicio = Double.parseDouble(etinicio.getText().toString());
            double articulo = Double.parseDouble(etarticulo.getText().toString());
            double cantidad = Double.parseDouble(etcantidad.getText().toString());

            float total = (float) (articulo * cantidad);
            float total1 = (float) (inicio - total);
            float porciento = (float) ((total1 / inicio) * 100);
            String porcentaje = Float.toString(porciento);
            tvporcentaje.setText(porcentaje);

            float suma = (float) (inicio - total);
            String resultadosuma = String.valueOf(suma);
            tvdisponible.setText(resultadosuma);

            float suma2 = (float) (inicio - suma);
            String resultadosuma2 = String.valueOf(suma2);
            tvcompra.setText(resultadosuma2);

            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbarra, "progress", 0, 100);
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            //iniciamos el progressbar
            anim.start();
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de escribir Compras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //toast.show();
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Primero Acepta la Transaccion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnceditar) {
        etinicio.setEnabled(true);
        etarticulo.setEnabled(true);
        etcantidad.setEnabled(true);
       }
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.danhermes.despensa.despensa">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cantidad Inicial" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etinicio"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Precio del Articulo"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etarticulo"
    android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cantidad" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etcantidad"
        android:inputType="number"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">

    <Button
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:background="#0984e3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aceptar"
        android:id="@+id/btnaceptar"/>

    <Button
        android:background="#ff4757"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comprar"
        android:id="@+id/btncomprar"/>

    <Button
        android:background="#4cd137"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Editar"
        android:id="@+id/btnceditar"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total de Compras" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvcompra"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cantidad Disponible" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvdisponible"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly_6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/pbarra"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Porcentaje" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvporcentaje"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: agrega tu codigo java. Una forma es con Visibility, mostraría un botón a la vez

Comment: Listo ya agregue mi codigo y mi archivo xml, pero la verdad es que no se mucho de java y quisiera saber si me puedes ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sería que al iniciar la activity solo muestre el botón Aceptar, y al hacer click
en el muestre los otros 2 botones y oculte el de aceptar.
Para esto tendrias que modificar el xml, a los botones comprar y editar

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Y en java al hacer click en aceptar (else) agregar

```
btncomprar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btneditar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btnaceptar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

en el botón editar:

```
btncomprar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
btneditar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
btnaceptar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: oye eso me ayudo de maravilla amigo muchisimas gracias me has salvado de reprobar jeje

Comment: solo una cosa mas, sabes como hacer que el prgoressbar este lleno segun el porcentaje que me de, de las operaciones que esten ahi?

es que eso no lo se

Comment: Has una nueva pregunta de progress bar ya que así podría servirle a otras personas.  Saludos

Comment: listo amigo, ojala puedas ser tu quien me ayude

Comment: POr favor me ayudarias con esta pregunta porfavor
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141366/porcentaje-con-progressbar

Comment: oye me podrias ayudar con esete [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141366/porcentaje-con-progressbar)