# Porcentaje con ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, botón, progressbar

que onda amigos que tal
me gustaria saber como le puedo hacer en base al codigo que anexare aqui, para que en un progressbar me muestre el porcentaje si por ejemplo yo hago quiero sacar el porcentaje de una cantidad X y ese porcentaje es X% como puedo mostrar ese porcentaje en un progressbar??

```
package com.example.danhermes.despensa;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class despensa extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etinicio, etarticulo, etcantidad ;
Button btnaceptar, btncomprar, btnceditar;
TextView tvporcentaje, tvdisponible, tvcompra;
ProgressBar pbarra;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.despensa);
    etinicio = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etinicio));
    etarticulo = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etarticulo));
    etcantidad = (EditText) (super.findViewById(R.id.etcantidad));
    tvcompra = (TextView) (super.findViewById(R.id.tvcompra));
    tvdisponible = (TextView) (super.findViewById(R.id.tvdisponible));

    btncomprar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btncomprar));
    btnaceptar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btnaceptar));
    btnceditar = (Button) (super.findViewById(R.id.btnceditar));

    tvporcentaje = (TextView) (super.findViewById(R.id.tvporcentaje));

    btnaceptar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btncomprar.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnceditar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnaceptar) {
        if (etinicio.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etarticulo.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etcantidad.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ingresa una cantidad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }else{
            etinicio.setEnabled(false);
            etarticulo.setEnabled(false);
            etcantidad.setEnabled(false);
            btncomprar.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btncomprar && etinicio.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etarticulo.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etcantidad.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Accion No permitida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }else{
        try{
            double inicio = Double.parseDouble(etinicio.getText().toString());
            double articulo = Double.parseDouble(etarticulo.getText().toString());
            double cantidad = Double.parseDouble(etcantidad.getText().toString());

            float total = (float) (articulo * cantidad);
            float total1 = (float) (inicio - total);
            float porciento = (float) ((total1 / inicio) * 100);
            String porcentaje = Float.toString(porciento);
            tvporcentaje.setText(porcentaje);

            float suma = (float) (inicio - total);
            String resultadosuma = String.valueOf(suma);
            tvdisponible.setText(resultadosuma);

            float suma2 = (float) (inicio - suma);
            String resultadosuma2 = String.valueOf(suma2);
            tvcompra.setText(resultadosuma2);

            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbarra, "progress", 0, 100);
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            //iniciamos el progressbar
            anim.start();
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Favor de escribir Compras", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //toast.show();
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Primero Acepta la Transaccion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnceditar) {
        etinicio.setEnabled(true);
        etarticulo.setEnabled(true);
        etcantidad.setEnabled(true);
       }
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.danhermes.despensa.despensa">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cantidad Inicial" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etinicio"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Precio del Articulo"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etarticulo"
    android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cantidad" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etcantidad"
        android:inputType="number"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">

    <Button
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:background="#0984e3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aceptar"
        android:id="@+id/btnaceptar"/>

    <Button
        android:background="#ff4757"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comprar"
        android:id="@+id/btncomprar"/>

    <Button
        android:background="#4cd137"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Editar"
        android:id="@+id/btnceditar"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total de Compras" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvcompra"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cantidad Disponible" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvdisponible"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp">

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ly_6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/pbarra"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Porcentaje" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvporcentaje"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta. Redactala de nuevo para que sea mas clara.

Comment: Listo amigo esta mejorado, espero y le entiendas

Comment: el String porcentaje es el que quieres mostrar en la barra?

Comment: de hecho ya me salio amigo pero no como quiero yo

Comment: hice una nueva pregunta, crees poderme ayudar?, ya me desespere
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141386/ayuda-con-progressbar