# Ayuda con ProgressBar

Tags: android, progressbar

hola tengo un problemita en eel siguiente codigo que mostrare, y es que como le puedo ahcer para que mi progress bar no valla de 0 a 100 si no que en vez de sero me tome una variable para sacarl el porcentaje
anexo el codigo del progressbar y el de mi operacion

```
            //Progressbar
            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbarra, 
            "progress", 0, 100);//En vez del 100 quiero traer el porciento de la operacion para sacar el porcentaje como le hago
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            //iniciamos el progressbar
            anim.start();

            //Operacion
            float total = (float) (articulo * cantidad);
            float total1 = (float) (inicio - total);
            float porciento = (float) ((total1 / inicio) * 100);
            String porcentaje = Float.toString(porciento);
            tvporcentaje.setText(porcentaje);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pensaria que es de la siguiente manera

```
//Operacion
            float total = (float) (articulo * cantidad);
            float total1 = (float) (inicio - total);
            float porciento = (float) ((total1 / inicio) * 100);


            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pbarra, 
            "progress", 0, (int) porciento);//En vez del 100 quiero traer el porciento de la operacion para sacar el porcentaje como le hago
            anim.setDuration(2000);
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            //iniciamos el progressbar
            anim.start();

            String porcentaje = Float.toString(porciento);
            tvporcentaje.setText(porcentaje);
```

Comment: Que realiza esto, en que ayuda al OP? , revisar [answer].

Comment: pues muestra el progress bar en % de forma animada. Y esa es la forma correcta de float a int: (int) porciento